# Opencsv export bean based on annotations

Tags: annotations, export-to-csv, opencsv, writer

I really like the `@CsvBindByName` annotation used to tell OpenCsv which properties should be translated when reading a CSV file.

Writing a CSV file with `BeanToCsv` seems more of a hassle, because you'll always need to specify the column names seperately in a mappingStrategy. Is there a way to use OpenCSV to generate CSV based on all (annotated) String properties of a bean, without using a seperate mapping / column list?